# Adding CSS rectangle within dropdown menu options

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, rectangles

I'm trying to add a small rectangle filled with color to the inside of a dropdown menu but it's not working. Ideally the option would looks like "red |||||" where the |||| would be a red rectangle. Here is the relevant HTML that isn't working (I'm aware that it currently makes all the rectangles red):

```
<select class="bootstrap-select btn" name="colorSelect">
        <option name="name0" value="0"  >red<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name1" value="1"  >green<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name2" value="2"  >blue<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
</select>
```

And CSS:

```
 .colorRectangle{
        width:30px;
        height:20px;
        background:red;
    }
```

Comment: You can't inject <span> inside the option - to create this specific design you should implement the select with divs and spans instead of <select> - because the ability to design select element is very poor.

you can look at this:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: Noted, thanks for the response. I guess I will play around with trying to reconfigure the form to use div and span. I wonder if I can still use "option."

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208814/6686121
it is possible with custom style css

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
<select class="bootstrap-select btn" name="colorSelect">
        <option name="name0" value="0"  >red<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name1" value="1"  >green<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
        <option name="name2" value="2"  >blue<span class="colorRectangle"></span></option>
</select>
```

And CSS Rules,,,

```
.colorRectangle{
        width:30px;
        height:20px;
        background:red;
    }

    .colorRectangle span:after {
    content:"";
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;

    }

    .colorRectangle span:first-child:after{
    background: red;
    }

      .colorRectangle span:nth-child(2):after{
    background: green;
    }

      .colorRectangle span:last-child:after{
    background: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me - thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

you must use list instead select option that because option doesn't accept childrin
try this:
[create box color in combobox option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917785/html-css-create-box-color-in-combobox-option/47918169)